# How do I use an NSImage as material of an SCNGeometry shape correctly?

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

I got a task in the university to add a picture as texture to the SCNGeometry Octahedron. It's my first project in Swift.

There are lot's of advices for the UIKit with UIImage class, but I'm using AppKit for macos and NSImage class. And none of the options I found in the web haven't worked for me yet. Probably I misunderstand something fundamental.
Well, firstly I dragndroped a picture named "sims.jpg" to my project folder and to art.scnassets folder. And also added them with File → Add files to "art.scnassets" and general folder. And did nothing with Assets.xcassets.

Then here is how the shape is created:

```
func createOctahedron() {

   let vertices: [SCNVector3] = [
       SCNVector3(0, 1, 0),
       SCNVector3(-0.5, 0, 0.5),
       SCNVector3(0.5, 0, 0.5),
       SCNVector3(0.5, 0, -0.5),
       SCNVector3(-0.5, 0, -0.5),
       SCNVector3(0, -1, 0)
   ]

   let source = SCNGeometrySource(vertices: vertices)

   let indices: [UInt16] = [
       0, 1, 2,
       2, 3, 0,
       3, 4, 0,
       4, 1, 0,
       1, 5, 2,
       2, 5, 3,
       3, 5, 4,
       4, 5, 1
   ]

   let element = SCNGeometryElement(indices: indices, primitiveType: .triangles)
   let geometry = SCNGeometry(sources: [source], elements: [element])
   let node = SCNNode(geometry: geometry)

   node.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = NSColor.green // назначаем цвет октаэдру

   let scnView = self.view as! SCNView
   scnView.scene?.rootNode.addChildNode(node)

   let rotateAction = SCNAction.repeatForever(SCNAction.rotateBy(x: 0, y: .pi, z: 0, duration: 5))
   node.runAction(rotateAction)
}
```

Just in case let me left a [full code](https://pastebin.com/vw4CUYRm)

So, I would add the image like this

```
let imageMaterial = SCNMaterial()
let image = NSImage.Name("sims")
imageMaterial.diffuse.contents = image
geometry.materials = [imageMaterial, imageMaterial, imageMaterial, imageMaterial, imageMaterial, imageMaterial, imageMaterial, imageMaterial]
```

Or maybe like that?

```
node.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = NSImage.Name("sims")
```

Or should I additionally map it somehow? Help me please because I really do not get it. Xcode outputs just a rotating octahedron with no additional texture, no errors either

Comment: Your image isn’t an NSImage, it’s a NSImage.Name. You can use that name to get the image with NSImage(named: ...)

Answer (score 1):

This line here:

```
let image = NSImage.Name("sims")
```

Only declares the name. You need:

```
let image = NSImage(named: NSImage.Name("sims"))
```

The reason your code compiles is that the `contents` property has a type of `Any?` so you can put any old goo in the property. It fails silently.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now it makes more sense to me. I changed the line for this one but my octahedron is still untextured. Is there anything else to fix or to add, what do you think?

Comment: You have an asset named “sims” in one of your assets folders?

Comment: Yes, but I'm still not sure if did it right So I took a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3G4w.png) and [one more](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zgx2y.png). Please check them. Do they seem relevant?

Comment: The assets folder looks right. Im wondering if SceneKit doesn't like JPG images. I'd 1) check you have an NSImage actually instantiated by using a debugger breakpoint 2) See what  happens when you use PNG format images.

Comment: There's no need to paste an image to the assets folder. Dragndropping it to the project folder right in the xcode is okay. And JPG images are as likeable as PNG. The problem was that I didn't specify enough data for the texture placement: I've described what worked for me below :)

Answer (score 1):

I found out what the deal was about. There was no texture appearing because of no UV mapping. I should have declared an array of 2d coordinates on the segment [0, 1] with the help of `CGPoint` and then add it to the `source` array.

Here is how it roughly looks like:

```swift
         let width:CGFloat = 1/8
         let coordinates: [CGPoint] = [
         CGPoint(x: 0,     y: 0),// BAC
         CGPoint(x: width, y: 0),
         CGPoint(x: width, y: 1),
         CGPoint(x: 0,     y: 1),// BAE
         CGPoint(x: width * 7, y: 0),
         CGPoint(x: 1,         y: 0),
         CGPoint(x: 1,         y: 1),// EDA
         CGPoint(x: width * 7, y: 1),
         CGPoint(x: width * 6, y: 0),
         CGPoint(x: width * 7, y: 0),// DAC
         CGPoint(x: width,     y: 0),
         CGPoint(x: width * 4, y: 0),
         CGPoint(x: width * 7, y: 1),// DFC
         CGPoint(x: width * 6, y: 1),
         CGPoint(x: width * 4, y: 1),
         CGPoint(x: width,     y: 1),// BFC
         CGPoint(x: width * 4, y: 0),
         CGPoint(x: width * 5, y: 0),
         CGPoint(x: width * 5, y: 1),// BFE
         CGPoint(x: width * 6, y: 1),
         CGPoint(x: width * 5, y: 0),
         CGPoint(x: width * 6, y: 0),// EFD
         CGPoint(x: width * 4, y: 1),
         CGPoint(x: width * 5, y: 1),
         ]

        let source = [
            SCNGeometrySource(vertices: vertices),
            SCNGeometrySource(textureCoordinates: coordinates)
        ]
        let element = SCNGeometryElement(indices: indices, primitiveType: .triangles)

        let octahedron = SCNGeometry(sources: source, elements: [element])
```

After we have specified the coordinates it's enough to wright the following:

```swift
        let image = NSImage(named: NSImage.Name("sims"))
        octahedron.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = image
```

And the image will be stretched on faces of our octahedron. 
The [full code](https://pastebin.com/cDfR0sqi) attaching